# Create Recurring Payments Profile

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Currently we are charging people on our website a fixed amount from their credit card using `DoDirectPayment`, but now we would like to add another option for users to pay in 3 installments over 3 months.

1) For that we need to create a `RecurringPaymentsProfile`, is that right?

2) Our `BillingPeriod` is set to once a month with 3 cycles. If we specfiy an `InitialAmount`, does that mean we only need 2 `TotalBillingCycles`?

3) Do we need to trigger any thing for the other installments or does PayPal charge the credit cards automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INITAMT is an optional, **non-recurring** payment and should have no bearing on your total billing cycles. everything else will be handled by Specifying the Regular Payment Period and/or Including an Optional Trial Period.